# USPS API not returning Commitment Date

Tags: api, usps

My client needs to know how long it will take to ship their time sensitive product for FedEx and USPS. I'm using the GetRates function of DotNetShipping but the Commitment Date is coming back as null and being set to 30 days by DotNetShipping which isn't helpful. Are there particular parameters for the USPS Web Tools API that have to be passed in in order to get a Commitment Date? I know that when I call the USPS API directly, with the following URL, I do get a Commitment Date in the return data.

```
http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=RateV4&XML=<RateV4Request USERID="[USPSUSERID]"><Revision>2</Revision><Package ID="2ND"><Service>PRIORITY</Service><ZipOrigination>44106</ZipOrigination><ZipDestination>20770</ZipDestination><Pounds>1</Pounds><Ounces>0</Ounces><Container>RECTANGULAR</Container><Size>LARGE</Size><Width>11</Width><Length>13</Length><Height>11</Height><Girth>55</Girth><Value>1000</Value><SpecialServices><SpecialService>1</SpecialService></SpecialServices></Package></RateV4Request>
```

The above URL won't work without replacing [USPSUSERID] with a valid user ID.

Answer (score 1):

I had to modify DotNetShipping to pass in Value and SpecialServices -> SpecialService and remove Machinable in order to get the CommitmentDate returned.